# Failed PHP 8.0 Upgrade

Tags: php, database

We are talking about a website which is used not very often. Today I mentioned that we are running an old PHP-Version. So I logged into my provider's control panel and adjusted PHP.

Afterwards I had no more access to the website.

I asked wordpress support informations and read, that perhaps some old plugins could be the reason. Of course I did not know the PHP-myadmin password any longer and so I changed it.

Failure #2: Since that time I lost the database connection.

I mentioned after a while, that this was a failure and wrote the new password into the `wp-config.php`.. But this didn't change anything.

By now I have a broken website without database connection

many many thanks in advance
KARL

Comment: your PHP error log can tell you what the problem was that brought the site down when you updated to PHP 8 and you can downgrade while you test but the database server issue isn't something people online can help you with, any answer would be unique to your specific situation and requires knowledge of how your specific server was set up. Once you've gotten your PHP error log and found the error messages that started happening after you upgraded PHP you can progress from there and edit them into your question. Your provider can assist with locating the log too

Comment: also your site appears to be up and serving pages

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress Development SE. This sounds like it might be a server config question. Tom's comment is a great start in debugging. You may need to ask more specific questions in other SE's depending on the issues you run into.